# globally change ZF2 form formatting

Tags: forms, annotations, zend-framework2

I'm building forms from entities

```
$builder = new AnnotationBuilder( $entityManager);
$form = $builder->createForm( $entity );
```

This is a great feature (saves me a lot of work), but what I want is to globally change the layout of these forms. I want to use a table layout instead of

```
<label><span>Name:</span><input type="text" value="" name="name"></label>
```

I want something like

```
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: extend the formRow viehelper andchange the wrapping

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you maybe elaborate? do you have a link where I can see how this is done? I guess I would create a class something extends ViewHelper - but how make my forms use this helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually was mistaken you do not need to actually extend or write a new viewHelper to achieve a diffrent kind of rendering.

In fact the `formRow` viewHelper has a partial parameter

`public function __invoke(ElementInterface $element = null, $labelPosition = null, $renderErrors = null, $partial = null)`

Once the viewHelper is called with that parameter set `<?php echo $this->formRow($element, null, true, 'path/to/your/partial'); ?>` it'll set following variables for your partial to use.

```
'element'           => $element,
'label'             => $label,
'labelAttributes'   => $this->labelAttributes,
'labelPosition'     => $this->labelPosition,
'renderErrors'      => $this->renderErrors,
```

Now you'll only have to write your own markup and you should be good to go.

Comment: ok I think I figured it out now, thank you, thank you so much for your help!